# Javascript, Print result before send it

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a project related to Sony.

I'm good at PHP, But unfortunately, I have some basics in HTML, CSS, and js.

I'm stuck with this js code

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
var _cf = _cf || [];
_cf.push(['_setFsp', true]);
_cf.push(['_setBm', true]);  
_cf.push(['_setAu', 'https://acm.account.sony.com/assets/59f4391f238ef6abd8cc30a515d5']); 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://acm.account.sony.com/assets/59f4391f238ef6abd8cc30a515d5"></script>
```

For example: If you put this code in your HTML file
This code automatically will get your User-agent, _abck cookie, etc.. And after that it will create Http post request and will send all these information

[Request Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sukXy.png)
,
And now how can I print the request payload before sending it, I want to print it on the console via this command console.log(?);

Comment: If you want to log it, just do `console.log(_cf);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems all the process are done in the script you referenced. The difficult is the script has been minified.

I guess what you need is an AJAX hook. Please take a look at:
[XHook](https://github.com/jpillora/xhook)

Add a hook before your Javascript code to console.log request info:

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/xhook@latest/dist/xhook.min.js"></script>
<script>
    xhook.before(function(request, response) {
        console.log(request.url);
        console.log(request.method);
        console.log(request.body);
    });
</script>
```

Hope this answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

wrap it into the function

```
var x = function () {
var _cf = _cf || [];
    _cf.push(['_setFsp', true]);
    _cf.push(['_setBm', true]);  
    _cf.push(['_setAu', 'https://acm.account.sony.com/assets/59f4391f238ef6abd8cc30a515d5']); 

   return _cf;
};
```

and now you decide when to run the function.

```
console.log(x);
```